# How to create a centered container that fits content programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

which would be the best way to create a centered (vertically & horizontally) container with unknown height (should adapt to whatever has inside of it) programmatically without using storyboards?

In the example below there is a full sized background image/color/whatever and there is a centered container. The container has no fixed height, it should adapt if I want to add or remove controls. The controls are spaced between them using constraints.

[image]

Comment: It's so easy to do it in interface builder, why would you want to do it programatically?

Comment: @AuRis - It's easy to do it in IB indeed but sometimes you need to dynamically adjust your layout. :-)

Comment: @AuRis Because I'm doing all the project programmatically already. In my case I think first you should know how to do it and understand it, then use faster tools/ways.

Comment: Well then you need to decide which one of the two you do programatically: set frames of your views or write constraints. The latter is a hell.

Comment: Add constraints programmatically... simple task.

Comment: It is absolutely not "hell" to write constraints programmatically.

Comment: Alright, perhaps I fear the unknown :)

Answer (score 1):

If your controls are as pictured, that's a perfect situation for using a `UIStackView`. It will expand, contract without you needing to do anything other than adding views.

You then use constraints on the `UIStackView` to expand / contract the containing white-with-rounded-corners view.

Comment: Actually the picture is only as an example. My whole app fits perfectly on the iPhone SE screen. When you run the app on a larger screen, the whole app is pinned to the top leaving unused space at the bottom. My objective is to center the whole app vertically. The smallest screen I already know it looks good. The app is basically a logo at the top, a label, a text field, button, image button, another button and a label at the bottom (in that order). I just whant everything centered

Answer (score 0):

in swift 4 you can do it like this:

**First way:**

```
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 60))
    view.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(view)
```

or using *autoLayout* :

**Second Way**

```
    let view = UIView()
    view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your `containerView`. The only constraints it needs are pinning to centerX and centerY:

```
containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Then, all you need to do is populate it with subviews, and make sure **those subviews pin to all the edges of the container view**. The container view can then self-size.

If your image is exactly what you want to replicate, you don't even need that second step: just make `containerView` a `UIStackView` with a vertical axis, and add all of its `arrangedSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

**First approach** is to use UIStackView.

**Second approach** is to generate constraints programmatically. I'll expound on this one because i mostly use it myself for various reasons.

I wrote the following extension - feel free to use it:

By using it, it's tremendously easier for me to constraint subviews in code.

I've made your use-case sample at the bottom of the item.

```
// MARK: Layout priorities which are mostly used
class LayoutPriority {
    static let required: Float = 1000
    static let must: Float = 999
    static let defaultHigh: Float = 750
    static let defaultLow: Float = 250
    static let zero: CGFloat = 0
}


extension UIView {

    // Make sure the view applies to autolayout rules
    private func validateViewForAutolayoutRules() throws -> Bool {
        // Implies it is the caller responsibility to make sure the view has superview
        guard let _ = superview else {
            throw ConstraintErrorType.nullifiedSuperview("Superview is nil");
        }

        // Enable autolayout mechanism
        if translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints {
            translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        return true
    }

    // This method assumes the two views share the same parent
    @discardableResult
    public func layout(_ firstAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute, to secondAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute, of view: UIView, relation: NSLayoutRelation = .equal, multiplier: CGFloat = 1.0, constant: CGFloat = 0, priority: UILayoutPriority = UILayoutPriority.required) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
        guard let selfValidationSuccess = try? validateViewForAutolayoutRules(), selfValidationSuccess == true else {
            print("\(String(describing: self)) Error in func: \(#function)")
            return nil
        }
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: firstAttribute, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: secondAttribute, multiplier: multiplier, constant: constant)
        constraint.priority = priority
        superview!.addConstraint(constraint)
        return constraint
    }

    // Set constant edge
    @discardableResult
    func setConstant(edge: NSLayoutAttribute, value: CGFloat, priority: UILayoutPriority = UILayoutPriority.required) -> NSLayoutConstraint?
    {
        // Enable autolayout mechanism
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: edge, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: value)
        constraint.priority = priority

        addConstraint(constraint)

        return constraint
    }
}
```

Now you use it that way:

- You create `containerView`, add it, and center it to it's superview (without setting height).
- You create first subview - stretch it to the sides and to the top of `containerView`.
- you create second subview - stretch it to the sides, it's top to the 
  bottom of the first subview, and it's bottom to `containerView`'s bottom.

That way 'containerView' is stretched vertically.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func configure() {

        // Generate container
        let containerView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(containerView)

        // Cling center of 'containerView' to it's superview
        containerView.layout(.centerX, to: .centerX, of: view)
        containerView.layout(.centerY, to: .centerY, of: view)
        containerView.layout(.right, to: .right, of: view, constant: -50)
        containerView.layout(.left, to: .left, of: view, constant: 50)

        // Setup first view
        let firstView = UIView()
        containerView.addSubview(firstView)

        // Set constraints on firstView
        firstView.setConstant(edge: .height, value: 50)
        firstView.layout(.left, to: .left, of: containerView, constant: 20)
        firstView.layout(.right, to: .right, of: containerView, constant: -20)
        firstView.layout(.top, to: .top, of: containerView)

        // Setup second view
        let secondView = UIView()
        containerView.addSubview(secondView)

        // Set constraints on second view
        secondView.setConstant(edge: .height, value: 50)
        secondView.layout(.left, to: .left, of: containerView, constant: 20)
        secondView.layout(.right, to: .right, of: containerView, constant: -20)
        secondView.layout(.bottom, to: .bottom, of: containerView, constant: -50)

        // Cling to to the first view
        secondView.layout(.top, to: .bottom, of: firstView, constant: 20)
    }
}
```